# When does $\| AB \| =\| A \| \| B\| $ hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality, matrix-equations, matrix-calculus

A matrix norm that satisfies $\| AB\| \leq  \|  A\| \|  B \| $ is also a submultiplicative norm, so, if $A,B$ are both square matrices, when does the equality hold?

Comment: it is pretty uncommon that it holds. Are you looking for conditions on matrices or on the norms ?

Comment: In general, you need that there exists  a vector for which $\|Bx\|/\|x\| = \|B\|$ and $\|ABx\| / \|Bx\| = \|A\|$

Comment: Conditions on matrices.

Comment: Can you specify the definition of the norm you are working with above? (Spectral norm?)

Comment: For the standard norm, a sufficient condition is that both $A$ and $B$ have a common eigenvector with largest eigenvalue each. Another is $A=cB^*$. The latter is necessary and sufficient for the Frobenius norm.

Comment: @charesp The answer is different depending on which specific norm you are asking about

Comment: Yes, sorry. I forgot to mention it. I'm asking about the Frobenius norm.